# Insert a single row and return its primary key

Tags: ssis

In SSIS, How do I use the execute SQL task to insert a single row with no parameters and get the primary key back so I can set it to user variable? My insert query is simply:

```
INSERT INTO [AdWords.ImportData] (EndDate) VALUES (null)
```

Comment: OLE DB or ADO.NET connection?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Good question, took me a few tries to figure it out.  Declare an SSIS variable of type Int32 (unless you need sizing for a bigint or numeric). I chose tablePk as mine.

### Option 1

**Execute SQL Task**

- General tab

ResultSet: None

SQL

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ImportData (EndDate) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT ? = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

- Parameter Mapping tab

Variable Name: User::tablePk

Direction: Output

Data Type: Long

Parameter Name:  0

Parameter Size: -1

### Option 2

This was the original solution as I couldn't grok how to get the placeholder `?` in a *normal* query. It couldn't as simple as what I had above, except it was.

The only difference is the query used

SQL

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)
, @paramDef nvarchar(500)

SELECT
    @sql = N'INSERT INTO dbo.ImportData (EndDate) VALUES (NULL);
    SELECT @ident = SCOPE_IDENTITY();'
,   @paramDef = N'@ident int OUTPUT'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @paramDef, @ident = ? OUTPUT
```

### Option 3

If you're using a data flow, I outline an approach on [How to Add the Result Set from a T-SQL Statement to a Data Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27954390/181965) In short, you need to add a column into the data flow prior to an OLE DB Command. Within the OLE DB Command, you will map that empty column into a `OUTPUT` parameter from your stored procedure and then as the stored procedure fires, it will replace the column with the value from the procedure.

Comment: None of these 3 options is using bulk insert. Is it possible to use bulk insert and get scope_identity?

Comment: @ile why *would* they demonstrate bulk insert? The question specifically asks about using the Execute SQL Task to insert one row. If you have a question on using bulk insert and the resultant identities, I would suggest you click the ask a question button. Provide a sample data and expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: yeah I see now that my comment weird... I did post a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583291/scope-identity-for-bulk-insert-in-ssis

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to bilinkc's version, without parameters:

Execute SQL Task

General tab
ResultSet: Single Row

SQL

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ImportData (EndDate) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastId
```

In the mapping of the single-row result set, enter LastId in the result name box, and map to your variable.

May well be marginally faster with a single output parameter (bilinkc's version), depends on how SSIS does it 'under the covers' and whether it creates a full datareader versus a single sp_ExecuteSQL call with output parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative I think is very clean.
It uses [OUTPUT syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) and the Result Set instead of Parameter Mapping, which requires less configuration.

```
insert dbo.ImportData (EndDate) 
output inserted.Id 
values (NULL);
```

- Replace `Id` in this statement with the name of your identity column.
- Use "Single row" as the Resultset type.
- No parameter mappings
- Add this to the Result Set
  tab: Result Name:  `0` (meaning the first column) and select your variable name e.g.
  `User::tablePk` (Variable type: Int32)