# How to pass out parameter from stored procedure to SSIS Precendence Constraints

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a SSIS Package in which I need to upload the data from an excel file to sql table after that I need to move the file to Some another folder depending upon some validations. These validations i need to do at database level. for that validations i have created a stored procedure and this stored procedure will return a output value. Depending on that value I need to move the file in a specific folder. I have use File System task to move the file, but I am not able to pass the value to the precedence constraint.

for eg. If my stored procedure return 1 I need to move the file to Failed Folder which is already created else to success folder.

Can Anyone help me to achieve it.

Your help would be really appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Problem 1, how do I get a return value from an Execute SQL Task? Problem 2, how do I use a precedent constraint?

Comment: What precisely does your SP return?

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914818/ssis-insert-a-single-row-and-return-its-primary-key/8917892#8917892

Comment: @Eric My output parameter returns 1 or 0 depending on some validations, if my all conditions are satisfied it return 0 else 1

Comment: billinkc yes I have both the problems that how should I return a value from Execute SQL task and how do i use a precedent constraint

Answer (score 0):

Use the stored procedure to assign the return value to a variable.

[image]

Then double-click one of the precedence constraints and insert the variable expression

[image]

Add the following to the precedence constraint, and the opposite formula in the other path:
[image]

Comment: Minor note, my reading of their question lead me to believe they are using the `OUTPUT` parameter. I thought your example had assumed a single row is returned but the Result Name makes me think otherwise.

Comment: That is a good point.  I have asked for clarification and if time permits I will amend the answer to account for both scenarios.

Comment: Yes I am using a output parameter to returned value and my stored procedure will always return only one value