# ssis package execut sp with variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I using ssis package.I want insert flat file source (text file) to sql.
Addres of text file is dynamic so i define variable for path.I have the sp like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_FileMaster]
  @FILE_PATH   nVARCHAR(MAX) 
 ,@id      int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 insert into [dbo].[FileMaster] ([FM_Name])
 values(@FILE_PATH))

 set @id = @@IDENTITY
END
```

I want exec this sp With variable parameter.
[image: variables window]

this is my package:

[image]

Which ssis tool should i use?and how to get output from sp (return parametert must be use in another sp in package)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to add an `Execute SQL Task` before your `Data Flow Task` (this will be at the Control Flow level).

You will need to configure the Execute SQL task as described in this answer.

[Insert a single row and return its primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914818/ssis-insert-a-single-row-and-return-its-primary-key/8917892#8917892)

Comment: thanks for answer.When i set connection string then Execute Package Task says 'Login failed for 'sa''.what is wrong?

Comment: Your connection string is invalid