# Get Inserted ID from OLE DB Destination using SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have used `OLE DB Destination` to insert data to the SQL server table. Is it possible to get the Inserted `ID` from the table without using query.

I can achieve this using

```
INSERT INTO testBook(name) VALUES ('Test Book')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

by selecting data access mode to `SQL COMMAND`.

But Is there any way to achieve this without using SQL query and using only the SSIS components?

Please advice.

Comment: is the problem solved?

Comment: You can use a `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM testBook` SQL Task to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Execute SQL Task

If i have this issue, i will add an `Execute SQL Task` after the `DataFlow Task`, and i will use the following command to get the Identity (*or i can use one of the Identity function to retrieve it*) :

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM testBook
```

And i will map the result to a variable

## OLEDB Command

You can also use `OLEDB Command` instead of `OLEDB Destination`. you can follow [This Article](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/24-Output-Parameter-of-Stored-Procedure-In-OLE-DB-Command-SSIS.html) for a detailed solution.

## Similar Questions

While searching i found these two similar questions asked on this website, you can refer to one of them.

- [Insert a single row and return its primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914818/insert-a-single-row-and-return-its-primary-key)
- [How to Add the Result Set from a T-SQL Statement to a Data Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932430/how-to-add-the-result-set-from-a-t-sql-statement-to-a-data-flow/27954390#27954390)

Comment: This will return incorrect results if you use Merge Replication. And in case of concurrent insert operations - you'll occasionally get wrong ID's.
Avoid assumption that your inserted ID is max' one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using OLEDB Command and a Lookup. Use an OLEDB command for inserting the data to the table. After that do a lookup using the fields you have inserted. This will return the inserted id for the values you inserted. Refer the following screenshot of the package.

[image]