# In SSIS, How to lookup ID for value, if no match, insert value and return ID

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup

With SSIS, I am loading a staged extract into its master database. Part of the process is using LOOKUP to get the ID of a string value, and if it doesn't exist, insert it into the reference table (with OLE DB COMMAND) and return that ID through a followed lookup.

[image: *SSIS Screenshot*]

The LOOKUP says no match for the first ~50 values even after inserted.
Is there a way I can fix this?
Or, is there another approach I should try?

Some research/attempts...

1. Originally, no matches were being returned. I had to change all the lookups to "No Cache" so it would reload the reference table (they are very small, so I doubt I'll have big performance problems).
2. An alternative I've seen is multicast into different lookups (based on columns I'm looking up), and merge join them back together after I've inserted/looked them successfully. But from what I've read, there are heavy performance issues with this approach.

I expect the lookup to match or not match.If not match, insert new value; then, lookup value again for ID (if no match, fail). Union both original matched and original not matched to do next lookup.

Comment: Your pattern would insert (or attempt to insert) the same "no match" more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

[image]

```
1.You are multicasting the dataset and grouping by just your lookup column
2.inserting your lookup and adding the scopeidentity(lookupid) to you grouped data
3.joining in the data you inserted to effective add your lookup value to every row
4.unioning your data back in
```

I am not positive, but you may need to add sorts to use merge join.

Comment: Note I used a script component to insert and return scope identity. I think you can do that with an OLE command but I am not sure. I find it easier to manage c# code than tough to find GUI attributes.

Comment: This also send all of the no matches down the insert path. This will avoid the "missing the next 50 or so". Note that Aggregate and Merge Join are stopper objects that wait for all records to be processed.

Comment: Also, I didn't go into detail on any one of those objects as they are questions among themselves. But this should give you the working template to get your project running smoothly.

Comment: After a day of troubleshooting, I finally got it to work! I think the number of components is going to down the performance, but I'm willing to sacrifice performance for now for a working model.
 
I'll post the final solution

Comment: Hopefully the path will rarely be used and all lookups have the entirety of the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

## SSIS Data Flow

[Here is the final SSIS data flow model...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwPyG.png)
Per @KeithL suggestion, I added sorts before the merge joins.

## Script Component

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    IDTSConnectionManager100 serverConMgr;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        serverConMgr = this.Connections.Connection;
    }
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        using (SqlConnection serverCon = new SqlConnection(serverConMgr.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO DIM.CONTRIBUTOR (CONTRIBUTOR) VALUES ('" + Row.CONTRIBUTOR + "') " +
            "\n SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT) AS 'ID'"
            , serverCon);

            serverCon.Open();

            SqlDataReader data = sql.ExecuteReader();

            while (data.Read())
            {
                Row.CONTRIBUTORID = data.GetInt32(0);
            }

            data.Close();
        }
        
    }
}
```

The "script component" is the trickiest part. It inserts the new value and retrieves the corresponding ID. Below is the code for that script.

Note 3 important things...

1. Database Connection manager (in this case, named "Connection", MUST be ADO.Net connection)
2. Row.CONTRIBUTOR_ID is a row I manually configured as an output in the "Inputs and Outputs" section of the script editor
3. "GetInt32()" method for SqlDataReader does not work with SCOPE_IDENTITY unless SCOPE_IDENTITY is explicitly cast as int in the sql command

Here are some other notes related to the script...

1. You CAN [insert and return SCOPE_IDENTITY through OLE DB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932430/how-to-add-the-result-set-from-a-t-sql-statement-to-a-data-flow/27954390#27954390), but it's fairly complicated
2. Here is the Microsoft Document reference to [how to retrieve data using SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)

Comment: A suggestion: try this without the reader part...  Row.CONTRIBUTORID = Convert.ToInt(sql.ExecuteScalar()); ExecuteScalar returns the value in the first column of the first row of results which is scope_idenity in your query.

Comment: Someone is going to tell you about SQL injection as well. You should use parameters.