# how to track row inserts done via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I need a way to track row inserts into all of my database tables for the given data import operation.  All row inserts are done via an SSIS data flow task (import from a text file).

When I run my SSIS package, I need to generate a unique ID to distinguish the given run from a later run of the same package (which can include closing the package).

For example, let's say this is the first time I run my SSIS package.  All of the rows from the text file land in their appropriate tables in my database.  Since this is the first "load", I generate an ID of 1.  This ID needs to be listed on every row that was imported.  (I'm thinking this is best achieved by adding a new column to each table to hold this ID.)  I close out of my SSIS package.  I open the package again and run another load.  (No rows will ever be updated or deleted.  The import will always be an insert / append operation.)  This time, a load ID of 2 is generated.  This ID will be added to all rows that were inserted during this second load.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What part(s) are you unsure about? It seems like you identified most of what needs to be done.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to generate a load ID in either SQL Server or SSIS.  Moreover, I need the counter for this ID to increment, even after I close the SSIS package.  And how would I populate this ID during an import operation?

Comment: There are a couple of ways that come to mind. First of all if all you have is a meaningless counter it doesn't really do much for you. I would think that something like an audit table would be far more useful. That table might have the datetime the package was executed or whatever you might want to track. Then your package could insert a row into that table and grab the identity value from the newly created row and use that. If you just want a numeric value look at using a sequence (assuming you are on 2012 or later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Variable, LoadID of type Int32.

Create a table called LoadHistory. This will track your import activity. At a minimum, it'd look like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LoadHistory
(
    LoadHistoryId int identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,   LoadDate datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Your package will now look like Execute SQL Task -> Data Flow

In the Execute SQL Task, you will insert a value into this table and get the identity value that is returned. I would use @[System::StartTime] as the value I load into the table as this is when the package began execution. You will get the scope_identity() value returned back and assigned into `LoadID` There's an example of this on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917892/181965

Now, within your Data Flow Task, add a Derived Column which inserts our 
@[User::LoadID] into the data flow path. Wire that up to your destination and all is good.