# Need to insert data into table and get primary key using scope_identity in SSIS

Tags: ssis, scope-identity

I am new to SSIS. Need help for below requirement.

1) Have a table called REPORTDETAILS which will store report details such as REPORT_NBR, REPORT_DT,CreatedBy,REPORT_NM,REPORT_LOCATION where in Report_NBR is the Primary key and Identity column.

2) I could store input data in separate variables and successfully add data to table using Execute SQL Task

3) But need to capture the primary key as output variable (need to use scope_identity) and pass it to next step which I am not able to do.

Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a single row and return its primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914818/insert-a-single-row-and-return-its-primary-key)

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for replying. I did try the solution provided in the post you referred. Since I had built a expression for insert sql query, ssis package errors out.

Comment: Hi Nick, I have added an expression to Insert query. INSERT INTO TLOG (REPORT_DT, CreatedBy, REPORT_NM, REPORT_LOCATION) SELECT GETDATE(), 'abc' , '[user::@FileName]', '[user::@filelocation]' Select ? = SCOPE_Identity().... This didn't work :( Please help me

Comment: In that case you'll need to post what you've tried and what issues you had. (i.e. the exact error message). Please don't post screenshots. Please post the actual code you used and explain the issue in detail

Comment: Also what is the "next step" here? You might find the best thing to do is encapsulate the entire thing in a single stored procedure rather than messing about passing variables between SSIS and SQL

Comment: Using stored procedure is good way? I had built the expression on variable since need to provide year-month-date for filename and file location. Do I need to send all values as Input parameter and get output of it through stored procedure? Once I get the Primary Key/Identity Column, I will have to use it in Select statement of next OLE DB SOurce task

Comment: ...and what does the next OLE DB source task do? It's quite likely you can do all of this in one stored procedure that you call from your package. Are you loading a bunch of records one by one then using their generated ID to do other stuff? If all of this is in the database then don't fluff around with SSIS tasks. Write one stored procedure to do it all

Comment: Are you doing something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605695/ssis-populating-cross-reference-table

Comment: Requirement is to add result set of a sql query into Excel file and 2 new tables. Here are the details:

1) We need to generate 7 separate excel files(reports) using 7 different sql queries
2) Need to first insert Report details like REPORT_DT, CreatedBy, REPORT_NM, REPORT_LOCATION into T_Report table and take the primary key which is identity column
3) Using one of the SQL query, will have to export the result set to Excel sheet and also to 2nd table

Comment: Problem here is : Say we get 10 columns from sql query which should go to Excel sheet, but while inserting into 2nd table I will have to add another 5 more columns as 2nd table should have content that went to excel sheet and also some more columns from 1st Table (Report table)
I am not sure how to run sql query only once and add more columns to it to add data to 2 nd table.

Comment: Things tried: Used Execute SQL task to store the Report ID which is expected in Step 2 (refer above) to write it to Output Variable, but it didn’t work. For 4th Step I know we can use either conditional Split or MultiTask, but not getting on what factor I can differentiate it. 
Last option is to run sql query and generate excel sheet and then use stored procedure to export data to tables. But don’t know whether this is efficient way. Please help, thanks in advance. Really appreciate your help

Comment: If I was doing this I would put it all in one stored procedure and export the result to excel. So you pass whatever parameters into the stored procedure (if any are even required). Inside the stored procedure it gets the next ID and runs the select for the excel output all in one procedure. Then you aren't passing things back and forth in SSIS. I don't understand  what you're saying in your other comments though