# Return the GUID Id from an insert using an 'OLE DB Command' in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my SSIS data flow I am attempting to use an `OLE DB COMMAND` to perform an insert into my table and return the newly generated `GUID` Id value.

Based on my [findings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914818/insert-a-single-row-and-return-its-primary-key), this is what I'm providing the `SqlCommand` property on the `Component Properties` tab

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
N'DECLARE @generated_keys TABLE([Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER); 
  INSERT INTO myTable ([FirstName], [LastName]) 
  OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @generated_keys 
  VALUES (?,?); 
  SELECT TOP 1 @ident = Id FROM @generated_keys', 
N'@ident UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT', 
@ident = ? OUTPUT
```

When I add this in and click the `Refresh` button on the `Component Properties` tab, I see the following error.

```
SSIS Error Code DTS_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
Error Code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
Hresult: 0x80004005   Description: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific 
error".
```

I'm using the SSIS add-ons for Visual Studio 2015 connecting to Sql Server 2014 database.  I have also checked and made sure that the database user has the correct permissions.

Comment: Does your query work if you run it in SSMS and plug in values for the "?" placeholders?

Comment: @TabAlleman - yes I have tried that as well and it works from SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the syntax of parameter definition but you missed `@ident` variable declaration and are attempting to put name or value or parameter to `sp_executesql` call which is not allowed. In the sample below `@ident` is declared and obtained from dynamic query.

```
GO
create table testtable
(
  id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null default newid(),
  [FirstName]   varchar(100),
  [LastName]    varchar(100)
)
GO
declare @ident uniqueidentifier

EXECUTE sp_executesql 
N'DECLARE @generated_keys TABLE([Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER); 

  INSERT INTO testtable([FirstName], [LastName]) 
  OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @generated_keys 
  VALUES (''test'', ''test''); 

  SELECT TOP 1 @ident = Id FROM @generated_keys', 
N'@ident UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT',
@ident OUTPUT

select @ident
GO
drop table testtable
GO
```

Probably you need the last line alike:
`set ? = @ident`
or to replace last argument of `sp_executesql` with `?`:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'...sql...',
  N'@ident UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT',
  ? OUTPUT
```

in this case I assume you won't need `declare` part.

Comment: I've tried using this example (without the testtable code) in my SqlCommand and it still throws the error -- I tried the 3rd param both ways (with the ? and as @ident)

Comment: For testing purposes try to: 1) put all this code into SP and call it with out parameter as needed 2) try to execute this code in SSMS with `execute as user=...`. This is not a server error message. You can also catch real one with profiler.

Comment: Gave both of those a try and it didn't help.  I'd still love to know how to get this to work, but for now I will just create a stored procedure to insert into each table I need instead

Comment: I don't have direct access to the DB server or SQL Profiler